# Django Rest Framework standalone?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Do I need to have a django website in order to use django rest framework, or can I use DRF by itself as a standalone app? Sorry but it is not so obvious to me. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There are some parts you can use without Django though it might need to be installed.

This question feels like this isn't the real question. Why would you need DRF without Django ?

Answer (score 0):

Well It's not that common but you can use Django framework's modules and classes in standalone scripts by importing Django.
For that you will need to add at the beginning of your code:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

Answer (score -1):

django rest framework is a wrapper of django from rest APIs. django is required for django rest framework